# Asp.Net Core Identity + Clean Architecture

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, clean-architecture

My solution is based on Clean Architecture.
The Domain project should be completely ignorant about the Infrasctrure layer.
The Infrastructure contains a Data Project and an Identity Project.
The Data Project is supposed to implement my repositories. It contains a class called ApplicationDbContext that inherits from DbContext;
The Identity Project is supposed to implement the AspNet Core Identity and all its needs. It contains a class called PortalUser that inherits from IdentityUser and also contains a class called ApplicationIdentityDbContext that inherits from IdentityDbContext;

In the Domain, I have an Entity called User.
User is referenced by several other Entities, like Company (A company has several users).

**I'd like to have only one table for both my entities User and the PortalUser.**

When I try to apply the migrations, I have several problems referencing User.

What I tried so far:

- Create an owned Property called User in PortalUser. But I can't map User in Company entity to an Owned Entity;
- Map both User and Portal User to the same table called User, using different DbContexts. But when I apply the migrations to the Database, the migration fails and says that "A table User already exists";
- Implement all properties from User in the PortalUser. But when adding a migration it fails and says that other entities like Company can't refer to User.
- Make ApplicationDbUser inherit from ApplicationIdentityDbUser but two problems: 1st, it's conceptually wrong to the Clean Architecture; 2nd, The same issues related to having only the PortalUser being created and all other entities referencing User.

I'm stuck on this problem and the project is not going far. All examples that I found so far are raw and don't show what happens when I have navigation properties referencing the User.
The better solution I could think of so far is to have two different tables, one for Identity and another for user needs and references. However, I'm migrating this solution from a messy solution to a more well-organized one, using Clean Architecture. The old version uses only one table for both situations and I can't have a new table and migrate the data.

PLEASE, anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have your User and whatever in the domain but have a **separate** persistence model in the infrastructure later. And a mapping between the two.